# file.isDirectory() always false in android with the path

Tags: android, android-file

ANSWER:

`Needed the call to getExternalFilesDir(p);`  like so:

```
String p = thepathblah; 
File path=context.getExternalFilesDir(p);
```

EDIT EDIT:

While I knew the `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` was returning just `Pictures/` I figured this worked because in android I assumed the file pointer was already pointing to your application space (sorta like in c#).   So in this:

```
 String p = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + s.getClient().getFirstName()+s.getClient().getLastName() +
 "/" + s.getPackage().getName() +
 (mSession.getSessionDate().getMonth()+1)  +  
 mSession.getSessionDate().getDate() +  
  (mSession.getSessionDate().getYear()+1900);
```

I thought was getting the full path, in fact I was writing a file out to this with no issues.  It turns out though to delete individual files (and load them) I needed a fuller path which ended up being:

```
 String p = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + s.getClient().getFirstName()+s.getClient().getLastName() +
 "/" + s.getPackage().getName() +
 (mSession.getSessionDate().getMonth()+1)  +  
 mSession.getSessionDate().getDate() +  
  (mSession.getSessionDate().getYear()+1900);

 File dir = new File("/sdcard/Android/data/com.software.oursoftware/files/"+p);
```

Not sure if I can take it that the above link is valid for all Honeycomb devices or not, specifically the `/sdcard/Android/data/packagespace/files/`

Is this safe to use this or do I have to do something more dynamic for honeycomb devices???

EDIT:  This is my little test function code to just write something to a folder...

```
   String p = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + s.getClient().getFirstName()+s.getClient().getLastName() + "/" + s.getPackage().getName() + (mSession.getSessionDate().getMonth()+1)  +  mSession.getSessionDate().getDate() + (mSession.getSessionDate().getYear()+1900);
            File path = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(p);
            File file = new File(path, "DemoPicture.jpg");

            try {
                // Very simple code to copy a picture from the application's
                // resource into the external file.  Note that this code does
                // no error checking, and assumes the picture is small (does not
                // try to copy it in chunks).  Note that if external storage is
                // not currently mounted this will silently fail.
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(data);
                os.write(data);
                is.close();
                os.close();

                // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
                // immediately available to the user.
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext,
                        new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String arg0, Uri arg1) {
                         Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + arg0 + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + arg1);

                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
                // not currently mounted.
                Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
            }
```

Then the way I try to delete this folder:

```
String p = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/" + firstName+lastName +"/" + pName+pDate;
File dir=new File(p); 
deleteRecursive(dir);
```

results in

`Pictures/ShaneThomas/Portrait882011/`

Which can write a file, tested that, but if I try to say:

```
void deleteRecursive(File dir)
{
    Log.d("DeleteRecursive", "DELETEPREVIOUS TOP" + dir.getPath());
    if (dir.isDirectory())
    {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) 
        {
           File temp =  new File(dir, children[i]);
           if(temp.isDirectory())
           {
               Log.d("DeleteRecursive", "Recursive Call" + temp.getPath());
               deleteRecursive(temp);
           }
           else
           {
               Log.d("DeleteRecursive", "Delete File" + temp.getPath());
               boolean b = temp.delete();
               if(b == false)
               {
                   Log.d("DeleteRecursive", "DELETE FAIL");
               }
           }
        }

        dir.delete();
    }
}
```

The dir.isDirectory is always false!?  I got this delete file/directories code off stack overflow but am puzzled as to why its not working?

and I do have this set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: What do you see when you log the dir.getAbsolutePath()? 
Is it directory path?

Comment: What is the question? Next time better answer your question below, instead of editing it infinite times. Now your text has become completely unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to add

`dir.mkdirs()` right after `File dir=new File(p)`. mkdirs() is the method responsible for actually creating a directory, not new File().

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons for `File.isDirectory()` to return false:

1. The path points to file (obviously), and not to directory.
2. The path is invalid (i.e. there is no such file/directory exists).
3. There is not enough permissions granted to your application to determine whether path points to directory.

In general, if `isDirectory()` returns true, you've got path that points to directory. But if `isDirectory()` returns false, then it might be or might not be a directory.

In your particular case, the path most likely does not exist. You need to call `dir.mkdirs()` to create all directories in the path. But since you need that to only recursively delete them, then there is no point in calling `dir.mkdirs()` just to remove that directory after that.

Comment: It is writing a file out to the directory and I can shell into my emulator and see it there...so thats what was perplexing to me.

Comment: What are permissions for parent directory?

Comment: hmmm its under my applications file space, I can in side the shell rmdir an empty dir and rm a file no problemo.  I edited the post to show I create the directory to begin with.

Comment: Fixed the issue and editing my question to reflect it, I am not sure if my fix is a safe fix or a total hack...

Comment: want to mark this for delete, figured out my stupid issue.  I need to do all my folder stuff with this call: `String p = thepathblah; File path=context.getExternalFilesDir(p);`

Answer (score 1):

Ok it's answered, but sometimes the issue fires because of sample reasone:permission :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if you forgot this permission you will always get false result.